# Nuxt: how to get path to static folder in script section (NOT in template section)?

Tags: vue.js, path, nuxt.js

I'm trying to call an instance of a certain [video player plugin](https://github.com/meyt/vue-md-player) in my template section:

```
<video-player :src="require(`~/assets/vids/${videoFileName}`)" />
```

But this causes a fatal error: "Cannot find module './'"

So I'd like to store the complete path to the file in a variable and then use that variable as argument in the template section.

Problem is, Nuxt docs ([here](https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/directory-structure/static/) and [here](https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/directory-structure/assets/)) don't explain how to get the path to either `/assets/` folder or `/static` folder from inside the script (JS) section - only inside the template/markup section.

Any idea how to get around this issue?

Comment: wait so you want to get the asset in `<script>`, but the above code you provided is in the `<template>` section right? did the error happen in `<template>` or in `<script>`?

Comment: In <template>. Basically the path featured in my post isn't valid. I guess I'm open to any solution as long as it works, because for now I cannot make it work.

Comment: which nuxt version are you using (assuming from the links, it's nuxt 2)? which `vue-md-player` version are you using? you can check them in `package.json` file if you're not sure

Comment: I'm using Nuxt v2.14.7 and `vue-md-player` v1 (based on https://github.com/meyt/vuemdplayer1-nuxt-example/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: have you tried using the `~static` alias ? also it seems that this fellow developper had a similar issue here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/4544#issuecomment-451700960

Comment: Thanks. If used in the template, I still get a fatal error. If used in script (through require(`~/static/vids/${this.videoFileName}`)), I get `_nuxt/static/vids/my-video-file.mp4` which translates in the DOM as `http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/static/vids/my-video-file.mp4` which does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your linked [github repo](https://github.com/meyt/vuemdplayer1-nuxt-example/blob/master/package.json) with Nuxt 2 and `vue-md-player` v1 I was able to play a video from the `assets` directory using a dynamic name with the following component code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <video-player :src="getVid" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { videoPlayer } from 'vue-md-player'
import 'vue-md-player/dist/vue-md-player.css'
export default {
  components: {
    videoPlayer
  },
  data() {
    return {
      videoFileName: 'video.mp4'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getVid() {
      return require(`~/assets/vids/${this.videoFileName}`)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

There was one additional issue I ran into with Nuxt 2 described and resolved in [this github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20564#issuecomment-1536201468).  I use `yarn` with my projects so my fix was to add to my package.json:

```js
"resolutions": {
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "5.0.0"
}
```

If you use `npm`, the solution is to use `overrides` instead:

```js
"overrides": {
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "5.0.0"
}
```

Be sure to rerun `yarn` or `npm install` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not getting the fatal error any more however it's still not working. `require(`~/assets/vids/${this.videoFileName}`)` returns `_nuxt/assets/vids/my-video-file.mp4` which translates in the DOM as `http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/assets/vids/my-video-file.mp4`, which does not work.

Comment: `localhost:3000/_nuxt/assets` is correct. I get the same thing but the video loads.  You've double checked your folder structure and filename?  Is `assets/vids/my-video-file.mp4` correct based on the physical file and location?  Do you have any errors in console or network tab? any specific status response code or message?  Please also post your `package.json` so we can verify your packages and versions.

Comment: Sorry I mixed things up, it works now. Thanks :)